# ng-model fot datepicker must be a Date instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to sum values where date = date choosed by md-datepicker.
Sum with users works good. But I am getting error when I want to do same thing with date.

```
Error: The ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance or a value that can be parsed into a date. Currently the model is of type: object
```

There is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/defuseer/mrp3qxgq/51/) with code

Comment: You are assigning an empty object to myDate, as can be seen in the html, where you put `{{myDate}}`.

Comment: @nadavvadan I fixed error but it still doesn't work can you check please? https://jsfiddle.net/defuseer/mrp3qxgq/54/

Comment: Your model is still not a Date `data.myDate` doesnt event exist. https://jsfiddle.net/02yu50p3/ Your codes doesnt make sense at all. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to show sum of task_time where date = date choosed by md picker liek it works with users. It sum every task_time for depts where user = user choosed in select